# select items whose category is X and whose category's parent is X

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, Items and Categories.

Items has recno, sku, description, price, brand, category, details, gender, size, color, dateadded. Categories has recno, category, parent.

The query I need, must select items whose category is X and whose category's parent is X.

I've tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT items.recno, 
                items.sku, 
                items.description, 
                items.price, 
                items.brand, 
                items.category, 
                items.details, 
                items.gender, 
                items.size, 
                items.color, 
                items.dateadded 
FROM   `items` 
       INNER JOIN `categories` 
               ON items.category = categories.parent 
ORDER  BY `description`
```

but that just selects everything. I tried to use joins but was never able to grab the items from the child categories.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    items.recno, 
    items.sku, 
    items.description, 
    items.price, 
    items.brand,
    items.category, 
    items.details, 
    items.gender, 
    items.size, 
    items.color, 
    items.dateadded 
FROM `items` 
JOIN `categories` ON items.category = categories.parent 
WHERE categories.category='x' AND categories.parent='X'
```

you have not added the `WHERE` condition in the query, that's why the result shows all rows

Comment: That returns an empty result.

Comment: what about WHERE categories.parent='X' ?

Comment: That kind of works, but it only selects items of that category, not of the child categories.

Comment: could you pls share your some sample data thru pastebin or sqlfiddle ?

Comment: Not sure I did that right, JOIN categories ON items.category = categories.recno JOIN categories c2 ON c2.recno = categories.parent
WHERE categories.category='X' AND categories.parent='X', but that returned an empty result.

Comment: JOIN `categories` ON items.category = (categories.parent OR categories.recno) pls try this

Comment: That doesn't work either. Is there a way I could do a WHERE that grabs anything where items.category = 'x' and where items.category = category.parent where category.parent = 'x'?

Comment: use OR instead of AND in WHERE condition

Comment: How do I force the first condition in the where and then OR the rest?